# wsl2 - why can't I ping my docker container by ip

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am in my wsl2 environment. Here is my container

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "ee4fd404f69fb60e4b81fa93e5fcf8e67609181353140b39a66bf6542df7a3d8",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ee4fd404f69f",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "a95056430f0bc148d56052466f310d9af8b74478e7434b5a5fc893e2824d691d",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "d26f79322e306b0f1243decf640dec954478d2d2aae10fb6360c4446387d5690",
                    "EndpointID": "a95056430f0bc148d56052466f310d9af8b74478e7434b5a5fc893e2824d691d",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Here are my very open firewall settings:

```
++ iptables -vL -n -t filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3230 packets, 1065K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
++ iptables -vL -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
++ iptables -vL -n -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
++ iptables -vL -n -t raw
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
++ iptables -vL -n -t security
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

When I ping the containers IP - it does not work

```
root@DewiJones:/home/dewi/dewi_ras_pi/nginx_test# ping 172.17.0.4
PING 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

More about my env:

```
root@DewiJones:/home/dewi/dewi_ras_pi/nginx_test# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:02:c4:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.57.248/20 brd 172.25.63.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe02:c4cf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:0d:fd:2c:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@DewiJones:/home/dewi/dewi_ras_pi/nginx_test# ip neigh
172.25.48.1 dev eth0 lladdr 00:15:5d:f6:91:50 REACHABLE
172.17.0.4 dev docker0  FAILED
172.17.0.2 dev docker0  FAILED
172.17.0.3 dev docker0  FAILED
root@DewiJones:/home/dewi/dewi_ras_pi/nginx_test#
```

Any advice?
thanks :)

---

more information:

```
the exact same thing works on my ras pi.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/tmp/nginx_test # ping 172.17.0.4
PING 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.179 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.304 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.4 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7159ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.119/0.155/0.304/0.058 ms
```

So maybe it's a problem with wsl2?

to answer the question of @Philippe

```
root@DewiJones:/home/dewi/code/rabbit-test/masstransit/GettingStarted# ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2078ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.035/0.068/0.102/0.027 ms

root@DewiJones:/home/dewi/code/rabbit-test/masstransit/GettingStarted# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         DewiJones       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.25.48.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Is `ping 172.17.0.1` working ? Can you post result of the command `route` It's a little strange your eth0 has IP `172.25.57.248`

Comment: I wouldn't expect the Docker-internal IP addresses to ever work, and you never need to look them up.  I'm a little less familiar with the WSL setup, but if Docker Desktop is in use and Docker is in a hidden Linux VM, then those IP addresses will be hidden inside the VM environment.

Comment: @Philippe I have answered your questions in the new edit. Please have a look :) thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your response. Just to be clear - this is ALL within my wsl2 env. I am not trying to ping from windows. What is weird - this exact same test works great on my ras pi. Very strange

Comment: How did you install docker on wsl2 ? Can you post result of `docker version` ?

Comment: @Philippe
dewi@DewiJones:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996

if I am honest - I can't remember how I installed it. If there is a "correct" way - could you post a link please?